# Elastic Search - List / Delete Document and Give more weight to recent Document

Tags: search, elasticsearch

I have a few questions on elastic search:

1. How to list all documents that are indexed
2. How to delete a doc from the index
3. How can I give more recent indices more weightage in search?
4. How can I add auto_time_add = True type thing in elastic search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the following for answers to your questions:

1. Refer to the [Match All Query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-all-query.html) for listing all indexed documents.
2. Refer to the [Delete API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete.html) for details on deleting docs from your index.
3. Refer to the Variable Boosts section of [Advanced Scoring in Elasticsearch](http://jontai.me/blog/2013/01/advanced-scoring-in-elasticsearch/) for an example of using [Function Score Query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) to boost more recent docs.
4. Use the Elasticsearch [_timestamp](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-timestamp-field.html) field